# How do I use jQuery Mobile characteristics on basic webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver

I created a jQuery Mobile Webpage recently using the program Adobe Dreamweaver CC 2014. In it, I found a certain capibility in the jQuery Mobile Website. This webpage was linked to the jQuery CDNs that were necessary. However, I found a certain capibility or function where the URL changed as I clicked on the the buttons. It wasn't the fact that they did, but rather it was the fact that the page stayed on the same url (hear me out). For example, if I were to click a button in the Mobile page, the url would have a pound symbol and whatever word or character that the tag is coded for and show completely different content. Ergo: "...webpage" to "...webpage#example".

I understand that creating a tag that looks like this:

```
    <a href="#sample">example</a>
```

would take the client to the URL ".../index.html#sample" once they clicked on it. This is the function that I would like to replicate except with one difference. In jQuery Mobile, the entirety of the page's contents change with a simple URL change like the one I just mentioned. For example, clicking one button would change the page's content but keep the client on the same html page but just add an extension with the pound symbol. On a desktop, if I would like to show my users a new page, I would send them from one html page to another to show completely different content. However, on jQuery Mobile, the user can remain on the same html document (index.html) but be seeing different content with every click.

In conclusion, I would like a way for the client to remain on the same webpage but see different content via "a" tags (or any way for that matter). But the part that is most crutial is the fact that I would not like jQuery UI (so the files for jQuery Mobile can be linked if necessary but no jQuery Mobile UI should be seen). Granted, it provides customization and creativity, however I just want the user to be able to go from the home page of my website to the about us page with the "#" symbol. Ergo: ".../index.html#home" to ".../index.html#about". It would be preferable if I would not have to use jQuery UI for the solution because I just want to "URL capabilites (if you will)" from jQuery Mobile into a personal website for leisure. It's just jQuery Mobile Templates and their UI don't show what I want in the way that I want it. Also, I am given to understand that the pound symbol is referred to as the hash.

I am somewhat new at jQuery Mobile and appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site. As you'll understand, the site format is not made to support tutorials (which are more long articles, or chat conversations than simple answers). So you'll need to restate your question using the [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You may also start with [HTML tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) and ask support here when you find a problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript in an `a` tag. Just make the change a JavaScript function.
example:
`<a href="javascript:toSample();"></a>`